# Flyway no migration script

Tags: c#, flyway

command
`flyway migrate -url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Sport -user=postgres -password=1 -locations=db`
does not migrate:

> No migrations found. Are your locations set up correctly?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It may be a problem with your [`locations` configuration](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/locations). When setting `locations` if you do not provide a location type prefix then it will assume the directory you have given is on the classpath. I'm assuming from your screenshots you're trying to read from the file system.
Try changing to `flyway migrate -url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Sport -user=postgres -password=1 -locations=filesystem:./db`

Comment: gives an error message ERROR: Skipping filesystem location:.\db (not found).